# Typo3: Use tx_news variables for Mask content elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news, tx-mask

I'm working with the news extension (by Georg Ringer) and want to use Mask content elements for the single news view. While creating a news article I found the possibility to implement other content elements such as the ones I have defined in Mask.

My question is how I can use the variables for tags and categories (and others) of the news extension in my Mask content elements? As far as I know the variables are not global so they can only be used within the news extension, right?

Thank you for your help!!

Michael

Typo3 V. 8.7.10, News V. 6.3.0, Mask V. 3.0.2

Comment: DOn't know if this is the right approach for you, but i once needed an additional argument, when changing from list to single view, and just added it to the f:link.action in the list view, more or less like this:

argument='{news: newsItem, myOwnAttr: settings.someAttr, currentPage: pagination.currentPage}'

Comment: To get Categories or Tags you can use Selectbox field in Mask Creator and fill Database tab, in that way you can fill drop down field to get list of  categories or something else in Mask element. I have working example with sys_category, it works great if you need for example select just one item from drop down menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! @Robert: in the version of the news extension I work with, another view helper is used (n:link ...) and there's no property 'arguments' for it. With the "configuration"-property I am able to add GET-parameters to the link but how do I read them out in my mask content element? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: PS: A more precise description what I need: I want to automatically insert the creation date, the author's name, the category and the tags into the output of the mask element.